# why do I get 24? when I have a date "2015-10-23T23:59:57"

Tags: javascript, date

I have a Date Object `"2015-10-23T23:59:57"`, invoke `getDate()`, it returns `24`.
I am very confused.

*Script*

```js
var d = new Date("2015-10-23T23:59:57");
var day = d.getDate();
alert(day);
```

Comment: Could you provide the used method?

Comment: `new Date('2015-10-23T23:59:57')` will create UTC date, As per your time zone it must be 24th Oct

Comment: As illustration of @Satpal's point, `new Date('2015-10-23T23:59:57')` on my system returns `Sat Oct 24 2015 08:59:57 GMT+0900 (JST)`, which is firmly in 24th.

Comment: var d = new Date("2015-10-23T23:59:57"); d.getDate();

Comment: Add the code to the question!

Comment: javascript can controll time zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Date('2015-10-23T23:59:57')` create UTC date. As per your timezone it must have been `24th Oct` thus you are getting `24`.

If you want to use the string to create Date, You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library.

```js
var cdt = moment('2015-10-23T23:59:57').toDate();
alert(cdt.getDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```